# Revision of a proof : if $\sum |a_{n}|$ is convergent then for $p>1$, the serie $\sum a_{n}^{p}$ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

If $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_{n}|$ is convergent then for $p>1$, the serie of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}^{p}$ is convergent.

---

Proof:

---

How $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_{n}|$ is convergent, by theorem, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ is convergent, so if you consider:
\begin{eqnarray}
 \frac{a_{n}^{p}}{a_{n}}=a_{n}^{p-1} \hspace{1cm}(*)
\end{eqnarray}
Now,from of convergence of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ by theorem, you know that:
\begin{eqnarray}
 \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_{n}=0
\end{eqnarray}
So, in particular, for some $s>0$
\begin{eqnarray}
 \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_{n}^{s}=0
\end{eqnarray}
From (*) you have:
\begin{eqnarray}
 \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  \frac{a_{n}^{p}}{a_{n}}= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_{n}^{p-1} \hspace{1cm}
\end{eqnarray}
the limit
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_{n}^{p-1}=0,  \hspace{0.5cm}\text{for} \hspace{0.5cm} p-1>0
\end{eqnarray}
So for $p>1$ we can conclude that:
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_{n}^{p-1}=0,  \hspace{0.5cm}\text{for} \hspace{0.5cm} p-1>0
\end{eqnarray}
by limit comparision test, the serie $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}^{p}$ is convergent. Do you right my proof? Have I had a mistake?

Comment: I think your proof is fine but you should explain the "by comparison theorem" a bit more

Comment: Sorry It's the limit comparision test

Comment: Simpler proof:  Exists $N$ so that $|a_n| \lt 1$ for all $n\gt N$.  Therefore for $n\gt N$, $|a_n^p|\lt |a_n|$.

Comment: What is $p$? An integer?

Comment: @PaulFrost I guess it, on the problem doesn't specific $p$ like a integer.

Comment: If $p$ is not an integer, then what is $a_n^p$ for $a_n < 0$?

Comment: @PaulFrost It's a complex number.